# Pull the data out of SQLite database and show it in Textview

Tags: java, android, sqlite, textview

Good evening, kind people of stackoverflow. I desire to pull **all the data** out of my database and to show it in a TextView. How can I achieve that?

Furthermore, I would like to pull the data (all of it) out of the database and send it via soap message to a WS far far away. I don't have any questions regarding WSDL set-up, but I do need information on how to pull the data from database and use it again and again.

Here is the code:

```
package com.example.prototype2;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

public class AddGlucose extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
  EditText etGlucose, etTime, etDate;

  DBHelper dbHelper;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_glucose);
 // Show the Up button in the action bar.
 setupActionBar();

 btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
 btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

 btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
 btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

 btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
 btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

 etGlucose = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGlucose);
 etTime = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTime);
 etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);
 dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
}

/**
* Set up the {@link android.app.ActionBar}.
*/
private void setupActionBar() {

getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.add_glucose, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case android.R.id.home:
    // This ID represents the Home or Up button. In the case of this
    // activity, the Up button is shown. Use NavUtils to allow users
    // to navigate up one level in the application structure. For
    // more details, see the Navigation pattern on Android Design:
    //
    // http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html#up-vs-back
    //
    NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
    return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
String glucose = etGlucose.getText().toString();
String time = etTime.getText().toString();
String date = etDate.getText().toString();

SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.btnAdd:
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");

  cv.put("glucose", glucose);
  cv.put("time", time);
  cv.put("date", date);
long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
  break;

case R.id.btnRead:
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");
    Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
        int glucoseColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("glucose");
        int timeColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("time");
        int dateColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("date");

        do {    

            Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                    "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) + 
                    ", glucose = " + c.getString(glucoseColIndex) +
                    ", time = " + c.getString(timeColIndex) + ", date = " +       c.getString(dateColIndex));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    } else
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
    c.close();
    break;

 case R.id.btnClear:
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Clear mytable: ---");

  int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
  Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + clearCount);
  break;
}
dbHelper.close();
}

class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public DBHelper(Context context) {

      super(context, "mytable", null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
      Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
      // создаем таблицу с полями
      db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
          + "id integer primary key autoincrement," 
          + "glucose text,"
          + "time text," + "date text" + ");");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }
  }

 }
```

Comment: textview.setText("ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) + 
                    ", glucose = " + c.getString(glucoseColIndex) +
                    ", time = " + c.getString(timeColIndex))

Comment: I don't really get your problem, since you already posted code that retrieves all desired data.

Comment: it goes to log, not textview. I'm confused and, due to lack of experience, interested in help

Comment: and, as I said, I'm also interested in exporting it to WS using soap

Comment: Well, now I am confused. Having written the posted code but not knowing how to edit a TextView seemed a bit odd to me. However, take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4873320/2098939).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just inserted so much code into one class and there doesn't seem to be a red line.
Follow this and the following tutorials and just change the explained code to your needs. Everything works perfectly and you will be teached how to get the information from the database after setting it up.

Databases are so essential that you should occupy on it a little bit.

[Tut 1](http://thenewboston.org/watch.php?cat=6&number=112)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a very good SQLite example code: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

So you only need to customize the code to your database, but I want to advise you, that it is easier and more comfortable if you create a custom object for the row elements (like the example code).