# Display some text from SQL by using JSON

Tags: android, json

I am at the beginning of learning an android
I was tried to get data from MySQL PHP to Android with JSON Object but But I do not know what to do after that in order to put the title in "@+id/txtTitle" and the message in "@+id/txtmessage"
sev_data code:

```
public class sev_data extends IntentService {
public static boolean ServiceIsRun = false;
public sev_data() {
    super("Service");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
    while (ServiceIsRun) {
        int id_s=0;//هنا رقم اخر رسلة وصلة التطبيق
        String url0 = "http://192.168.1.7/jeson/sendapp.php?co>"+id_s;//رايط ملف الداتة من السيرفر
        String  NewsData;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(url0);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            NewsData = Stream2String(in);
            in.close();
            JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(NewsData);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("date");
            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String id= jsonObject.optString("id");
                String title = jsonObject.optString("title");
                String mess = jsonObject.optString("mess");
                ///// هنا نهاية الموضوع دي اخر رسلة علي السيرفر
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("mmmm", "hhhhhhhh", e);
        }
    }
}
public String Stream2String(InputStream inputStream) {
    BufferedReader bureader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    String Text = "";
    try {
        while ((line = bureader.readLine()) != null) {
            Text += line;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return Text;
}
}
```

Comment: did you mean,You want to show data on ui?

Comment: Read about TextView https://stackoverflow.com/a/4873309/6699069 And also mention what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

As you are beginner start with a volley Library.

http://androtech1tk.000webhostapp.com/2017/09/android-working-with-volley-library

Answer (score 0):

first, you should get the object of the id txtTitle and txtmessage, for example, using findViewById call
second, update the string to the object by using the setText() method of the object you get in the first step

then, you will see the string on the UI

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment ,
But is it possible to explain this with a simple code please

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
private TextView textView1;
...

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
    String str = "This is title";

    textView1.setText(str);
    ...
 }
```